# Setting values to TextFields

Tags: android, testing, textview

I'd like to write a test that simply test that I have the correct mapping between the fields in my layout and the resulting business object. But when I attempt to set values to my textfields I get an error that says that I should not attempt to set values to the textfields from another thread. So basically I can't setup the activity to a state where I can attempt to create my business object.

But how to write a test like this? I'd prefer if I don't have to add code to the activity that are only to support the test, but maybe I can't avoid that?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View objects can only be accessed from the UI thread. You must be trying to set those values from a work thread you have created somewhere else.

You should have a look at the AsyncTask class to see if that can solve you problem (it has functions that are executed on the UI Thread like onResult, onProgress, ...)

Other possibility is to use the Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) function.

That's all I can say with the details you have given. Maybe if you post some sample code you'll get some more precise answers.

Comment: I solved the problem using runOnUiThread and a Thread.sleep(50) to allow for the ui to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your Activity are you trying to set the TextField?

If you just need a simple test, you can do it via the onCreate method. Below is a snippit from my functional code:

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ){  
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.main );
    _dateView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.ScheduleDate );
    _dateView.setText( "TODAY" );
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the value of the TextView from my test in order to see if my "save"-method actually reads the values correctly from fields in the activity.

Comment: @Roland, you should follow the example I put above in order to set your values in the TextField.

Comment: I solved the problem having my test to use the runOnUiThread-method. That way I could set the values of the textfields from my text. Your example sets the values inside the Activity itself, but that would interfer with my application.